# 2 timers after a page "refresh"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Using setInterval to do some actions. After a submitting the form (jQuery mobile) the page is refreshed, with the bad side effect that now 2 timers are active. Why is the first timer not ended after a submit and/or how to prevent starting a second timer? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Writing your code may help people answer your question.

Comment: Just a suggestion for the future post. Whenever posting any question on the SO, please do also post the HTML markup and the code that you have tried. That would help us to provide better answers!

Comment: pls add your code of JQM, our answers will more likely be _guessing_. Anyway, try `pageinit` to fire the timer and ’pageshow` to kill it, as `pageinit` is fired once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably because the form is submitted with ajax and the setInterval javascript gets re-executed someway.

Try using

```
window.timer = window.timer || setInterval(....);
```

Answer (score 0):

setInterval returns an integer (let's say the "id" of your timer).
Knowing that, you can easily, by storing this id:
- Stop your first timer before starting the second (function stopInterval(id))
- Prevent it from starting a second time